# Finding the campuses where are the classes are taught

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have CAMPUS_IDs(NY1, PA1, VA1) and CLASS_IDs(around 10 classes)
So i have to create a table that has columns Campus_id and Class_id and assign in which campus the classes are taught. The problem is that some classes are taught in all campuses and some of them are taught in just one campus. How to design that table? I tried to create following table but it is messy:

```
_____________________
| class_id  |campus_id
---------------------
| math101   | NY1    |
---------------------
| pyt218    | PA1    |
---------------------
| C767      | VA1    | 
---------------------
| pyt218    | PA1    |
_____________________
```

and the campus_id with class_id are foreign keys for another tables.

Comment: That looks correct to me, what is the problem?

Comment: problem is math101 for example may be taught in NY1 and PA1 campuses.

Comment: That would be two entries in the class_campus table. One for math101 in NY1 and one for math101 in PA1. You would make the combination of class_id and campus_id unique in the table. Your current sample has pyt218 linked to PA1 two times, which I don't think is valid. If that is, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to list all Campuses where the classes are taught? For an output like

```
class_id | campus_id
math101  | NY1, PA1
pyt218   | PA1, VA1, NY1
...
```

you can use the wm_concat function available in Oracle 10g:

```
with d as (
  select 'NY1' as campus_id, 'math101' as class_id from dual union all 
  select 'PA1' as campus_id, 'math101' as class_id from dual union all 
  select 'VA1' as campus_id, 'pyt218' as class_id from dual union all 
  select 'PA1' as campus_id, 'pyt218' as class_id from dual union all 
  select 'PA1' as campus_id, 'class3' as class_id from dual union all 
  select 'VA1' as campus_id, 'class3' as class_id from dual union all 
  select 'VA1' as campus_id, 'math101' as class_id from dual union all 
  select 'NY1' as campus_id, 'class3' as class_id from dual
)
select class_id, wm_concat(campus_Id)
From d
group by class_id
```

In Oracle 11.2, there is a new function "listagg" which can be used to generate the same result:

```
with d as (
  select 'NY1' as campus_id, 'math101' as class_id from dual union all 
  ...
)
select class_id, listagg(campus_id, ',') within group (order by campus_id)
From d
group by class_id
```